# How can I disable modern standby?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hp

I got a new laptop. It has modern standby, and to be frank it's the *worst* I've ever tried:

- If I leave it *on* for fifteen minutes, it goes to standby. On wakeup it rediscovers all connected monitors, so suddenly all windows are cramped on one monitor, not in the layout I had.
- It disconnects RDP sessions to other machines.
- When I actually *want* it to sleep, it still listens to for instance bluetooth... somewhat. It disconnects every minute, so when listening to music on the bus from my cellphone, my headset goes "device connected"..."device disconnected".

So in short:

- When I tell my laptop to sleep, I want it to sleep. Not any active interfaces. If it takes ten seconds to wake, that's fine.
- When I don't tell it to sleep, stay powered on.

So in short: how can I get rid of modern sleep?

The proposed duplicates are not relevant:

- Microsoft has removed the registry setting in Win10 22H1 update, so that modern standby is *always* available.
- I don't want to enable it, like one of the suggested duplicates.

I have not found any up to date Questions that deals with how to disable modern standby.

Comment: Provide the log file from powercfg /sleepstudy as an edit to your question

Comment: @Ramhound that's a *large* (365kB) html file. Is all of it of interest, or some piece of it?

Comment: Just the important information